# MYSQL count for each value in field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database with the following table "responses" with an id and a U.S. state:

```
*id   *state
1     CA
2     NY
3     NY
4     CO
5     DE
```

I'm using PHP to output the total number of rows for each of the 50 states in the U.S.

So, my output would look like:
CA: 1
NY: 2
CO: 1
DE: 1
etc...

I know I can run 50 queries like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `responses` 
WHERE state='CA'
```

My question is: is there a more efficient way to handle this, or do I need to run 50 queries?

Comment: SELECT state, count(state) from responses GROUP BY state

Comment: Also, note with these aggregate functions and group by clauses your table result set will contain the number (the count), so you don't need to compute a running total or row count on the PHP side.  Just read from the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT state, COUNT(*) FROM `responses` GROUP BY state;
```

There are [many good tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) on using GROUP BY, and it's one of the most useful and powerful features of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) clause which will group all of the results by the `state`:

```
SELECT
    state, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
    `responses`
GROUP BY
    state;
```